# 'ConnectyCube/ConnectyCube.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, videochat, connectycube

I had created the new Objective C project and installed ConnectyCube Video call and QMChat SDK. Check the following pod files.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Connecty' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Connecty

   pod 'QMChatViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/ConnectyCube/ios-chat-view-controller.git', :branch => 'master'
   pod 'QMServices', :git => 'https://github.com/ConnectyCube/sdk-ios-services.git'
   pod 'ConnectyCubeCalls'

  target 'ConnectyUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

When i run the project, I'm getting `'ConnectyCube/ConnectyCube.h' file not found` error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqrXS.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have not connected [ConnectyCube iOS Chat SDK](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-ios-sdk-releases) yet.

ConnectyCube Chat API is used as a signaling transport for Video Calling API, so in order to start using Video Calling API you need to connect to Chat.

Chat View Controller and iOS Services are additional SDKs and they do not replace the core one.

Please try connecting Chat SDK as well according to this [guide](https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/).